# Which route when combining two HTML create forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have the routes

```
/magazines/new
/magazines/:magazines_ads/new
```

but I want to display both forms on the same page, because they are very small and for convenience it would make more sense. How would one handle this situation normally?

Comment: Do you want to handle them in the same form?

Comment: @techvineet Not. Actually both resources are created through file imports.

Comment: You comment is not clear.

Comment: Just two separated forms on on page. Each form get its own url. Where is the problem? Or do you want to create both resources at the same time (with one post), than try nested_attributes and nested forms.

Comment: @techvineet What I meant is: I don't use a HTML form, where you fill out fields and click on submit. Both pages are HTML sites where the user can upload files, the uploaded files are parsed from which content the resources are created. That's what I meant. The routes I have posted describe the path to the HTML page for creating resources.

Comment: @spickermann I am not talking about the POST command, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions The `/new` path is used to GET the HTML site for resource creation. So my question is, how to combine two HTML pages that actually reside on different paths. I think gpalyan has answered that I just get confused about which path to use for combining both.

Comment: You need to create your forms with form_tag then.

Comment: @frandroid So I should use form_tags, even so my resources are not created through user input on HTML forms, but through file imports?

Comment: A file import is a kind of input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two ajax calls to pull the forms in. Something like:

```
jQuery.ajax({url:"/magazines/new"...})
```

and

```
jQuery.ajax({url:"/magazines/:magazine_ads/new"...})
```

and then write their html to different parts of the page.

Comment: And on which route should I display the combinbed form? What's the RESTful approach there?

Comment: Good question. I suppose you'd need a new route for that. Why not combine these two forms to one route instead of having the two routes? Have one call generate the html for both forms.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding now, too. In this case the combined route would just be `/magazines/new` or what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i have understood the question but can we do something like this

```
resources :magazines do
  resources: magazines_ad
end
```

and then use rails nested form to combine both form together